# GraphQL, how to return type of byte[]

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I have thumbnails saved in my database as a byte array. I can't seem to workout how to return these to the frontend clients via GraphQL.

In a standard REST approach I just send a POJO back with the bytes and I can easily render that out.

However trying to return a `byte[]` is throwing

> Unable to match type definition (ListType{type=NonNullType{type=TypeName{name='Byte'}}}) with java type (class java.lang.Byte): Java class is not a List or generic type information was lost: class java.lang.Byte

The error is descriptive and tells me what's wrong, but I don't know how to solve that.

My `thumbnail.graphqls` looks like:

```
type Thumbnail {
    id: ID!
    resource: [Byte!]
}
```

And the thumbnail POJO

```
public class Thumbnail extends BaseEntity {
    byte[] resource;
}
```

I'm using `graphql-spring-boot-starter` on the Java side to handle things, and I think it supports `Byte` out the box, so where have I gone wrong?

Very fresh to GraphQL so this could just be an obvious mistake.

Cheers,

Comment: I think your issue is that you try to serialize a binary array to json (I guess you return json from your controller). How do you imagine  thatyour response should look like?

Comment: I would expect the result from GraphQL to look the same as it does from a REST request. So effectively the `byte[]` would look like a string of bytes... It's just how do I get GraphQL to accept that is a valid response type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to serialize it to one of the standard types.
If you want your byte array to look like a string such as "F3269AB2", or like an array of integers such as [1,2,3,4,5] its totally up to you.

You can achieve the serialization by writing a resolver for your entity, like that:

```
public class ThumbnailResolver extends GraphQLResolver<Thumbnail> {
        public String resource(Thumbnail th) { ... }
        //or List<Integer> resource(Thumbnail th) { ... }
        //or whatever
    }
```

The resolver have always priority over your entity. This means that if a resolver method with the correct name, parameters and return type is found in the resolver class, this will be called instead of the entity method. This way we can "override" entity methods, in order to return an other result, even a different type than the actual entity field. By using resolvers, we could also have access to application scoped services etc that an entity typically does not have.

After writing your resolver, don't forget to update your schema file to:

```
resource: String
#or resource:[Int]
#or whatever
```

Your schema should refere to the resolver type since this is what graphQL recieves. The actual entity type will become then irrelevant to graphQL.

As a plan B, you could implement a new Scalar. This would be like inventing a new basic type. This is also not that hard. You can see the already existing scalar types [here](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/Scalars.java) and do something similar.

You can then name your new type ByteArray or something like that, declare it in your schema:

```
scalar ByteArray
```

and then use it.

I would go for the first solution though since it is easier and faster to implement.

Comment: this answer doesn't provide the issue solution, it's just an part of idea